# removing sites from the network icon in the system tray

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, notification-area

With a lot of traveling to various hotels with free Wi-Fi I have collected a number of sites in the system tray when I clicked on the network icon. I doubt highly that I will return to these hotels and so the various sites will not be needed again. How do I remove the sites – where are they even stored? I went browsing through the registry and could not find them. (Were talking about 25-35 sites I want to blow away) any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you.

Ross

Answer (score 1):

It's in the control panel for "Manage Wireless Networks" which you can enter into a Windows search box to find.

[image]